# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for (?, ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have written the following unit test for my Angular 10 component, which basically displays a tree view with some interactivity:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
// import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TreeviewModule } from 'ngx-treeview';
import { DocumentTreeService } from '../services/DocumentTreeService';

import { DocumentTreeviewComponent } from './document-treeview.component';

describe('DocumentTreeviewComponent', () => {
  let component: DocumentTreeviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DocumentTreeviewComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DocumentTreeviewComponent ],
      imports: [ TreeviewModule.forRoot(), ReactiveFormsModule, MatProgressBarModule,
         BrowserModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, /* MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule */ ],
      providers: [ DocumentTreeService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DocumentTreeviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My DocumentTreeService.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TreeviewItem } from 'ngx-treeview';
import { GlobalDataService } from './global-data.service';

interface TreeItem {
  name?: string;
  text: string;
  value: any;
  children?: String[];
  type: 'folder' | 'document';
}

/* tslint:disable no-string-literal prefer-for-of */
export class DocumentTreeService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public DataService: GlobalDataService){}
  public treeviewmtextresponse;
  public docNames = [];

  public FolderItems = [];
  public treeviewItem = [];
  public finalTreeviewElements: TreeviewItem[] = [];

  getDocItems(): TreeviewItem[] {
    const docItems = [];

    // TEMPORARY SOLUTION (QUICKFIX) FOR 1 DOC
    if (!this.treeviewmtextresponse.length) {
      const element = this.treeviewmtextresponse['documentName'];
      this.docNames.push(element);
      const tempArray = element.split('!');
      if (!this.FolderItems.includes(tempArray[0])) {
        this.FolderItems.push(tempArray[0])
      }

      docItems[tempArray[0]] = this.docNames.filter(s => s.includes(tempArray[0] + '!'));
      for (let o = 0; o < docItems[tempArray[0]].length; o++) {
        docItems[tempArray[0]][o] = docItems[tempArray[0]][o].replace(tempArray[0] + '!', '');
        const documentItem: TreeItem = {
          text: docItems[tempArray[0]][o],
          type: 'document',
          value: docItems[tempArray[0]][o],
        }
        docItems[tempArray[0]][o] = documentItem;
      }
    }
    // TEMPORARY SOLUTION (QUICKFIX) FOR 1 DOC

    for (let m = 0; m < this.treeviewmtextresponse.length; m++) {
      const element = this.treeviewmtextresponse[m]['documentName'];
      this.docNames.push(element);
      const tempArray = element.split('!');
      if (!this.FolderItems.includes(tempArray[0])) {
        this.FolderItems.push(tempArray[0])
      }

      docItems[tempArray[0]] = this.docNames.filter(s => s.includes(tempArray[0] + '!'));
      for (let o = 0; o < docItems[tempArray[0]].length; o++) {
        docItems[tempArray[0]][o] = docItems[tempArray[0]][o].replace(tempArray[0] + '!', '');
        const documentItem: TreeItem = {
          text: docItems[tempArray[0]][o],
          type: 'document',
          value: docItems[tempArray[0]][o],
        }
        docItems[tempArray[0]][o] = documentItem;
      }
    }

    let jsonString;
    for (let p = 0; p < this.FolderItems.length; p++) {
      const element = this.FolderItems[p];
      const treeItem: TreeItem = {
        name: element + "!" + docItems[element][0]["text"],
        text: element,
        value: element,
        type: 'folder',
        children: docItems[element],
      }
      const DokData = treeItem["name"];
      this.DataService.SelectedDocumentList.push(DokData);

      jsonString = JSON.stringify(treeItem);
      const finalObject: TreeviewItem = new TreeviewItem(
        JSON.parse(jsonString));
      this.finalTreeviewElements.push(finalObject);
    }
    return this.finalTreeviewElements;
    }
}
```

My full error message:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DocumentTreeService: (?, ?).
```

I originally thought I messed up with placing the service in the correct category but with trial and error and some logic I determined it was set correctly. What's causing this issue?

---

## Update 1

My current codebase looks like this:

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
    const httpSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']); //funcName for any function name that you need to exist on the spy objects
    const dataSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GlobalDataService', ['funcName']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DocumentTreeviewComponent ],
      imports: [ TreeviewModule.forRoot(), ReactiveFormsModule, MatProgressBarModule,
         BrowserModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, HttpClientTestingModule, MatDialogModule, MatInputModule
         /* MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule */ ],
      providers: [ GlobalDataService, DatePipe,
        { provide: DocumentTreeService, useValue: mockDocumentTreeService },
        { provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpSpy },
        { provide: GlobalDataService, useValue: dataSpy }] // modify this line to provide a mock
    })
    .compileComponents();
       // To access the service from your tests
    documentTreeService = TestBed.inject(DocumentTreeService);
  });
```

## Update 2

the document-treeview.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeviewItem, TreeviewConfig } from 'ngx-treeview';
import { GlobalDataService } from '../services/global-data.service';
import { DocumentTreeService } from '../services/DocumentTreeService';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-document-treeview',
  templateUrl: './document-treeview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./document-treeview.component.scss']
})

export class DocumentTreeviewComponent implements OnInit {
  dropdownEnabled = false;
  items: TreeviewItem[];
  values: number[];
  config = TreeviewConfig.create({
    hasAllCheckBox: false,
    hasFilter: true,
    hasCollapseExpand: true,
    maxHeight: 435
  });

  constructor(public service: DocumentTreeService, public DataService: GlobalDataService) {
    this.getDocumentList(false);
   }

  public docAmount;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(()  => {
      if (!this.items && this.service.treeviewmtextresponse) {
        if (this.service.finalTreeviewElements.length !== 0) {
          this.items = this.service.finalTreeviewElements;
        } else {
            this.items = this.service.getDocItems();
        }
      }
      if (this.DataService.newDocumentAdded === true || this.DataService.documentDeleted === true) {
        this.resetDocuments();
        if (this.service.treeviewmtextresponse.length > this.docAmount && this.DataService.newDocumentAdded === true || this.service.treeviewmtextresponse.length < this.docAmount && this.DataService.documentDeleted === true) {
          this.DataService.newDocumentAdded = false;
          this.DataService.documentDeleted = false;
          this.docAmount = this.service.treeviewmtextresponse.length;
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  public resetDocuments() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // reset treeview arrays
      this.items = null;
      this.service.docNames = [];
      this.service.FolderItems = [];
      this.service.treeviewItem = [];
      this.service.finalTreeviewElements = [];
      // reset treeviewmtextresponse
      this.service.treeviewmtextresponse = null;
      this.getDocumentList(true);
  }, 1000);
  }

  onFilterChange(value: string): void {
    console.log('filter:', value);
  }

  public getFolderName(event) {
    // irrelevant for the unit test
  }

  openTonicUrl(event){
    // this.openDialog(event);
    if (this.DataService.SelectedDocumentName) {
      window.open(`${environment.APIUrl}/text/gui/open/%5Chome%5Ctestproject%5C` + this.DataService.SelectedDocumentName, '_blank');
    }
  }

  public getDocumentList(refresh: boolean) {
    return this.service.http.get(this.DataService.getDocumentUrl, this.DataService.httpOptions)
    .subscribe(
      documentResponse => {
        this.service.treeviewmtextresponse = documentResponse['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body'][
          'ns2:getDocumentsResponse'
        ]['return'];
        if (refresh === false) {
          this.docAmount = this.service.treeviewmtextresponse.length;
        }
        this.DataService.documentListLoaded = true;
       },
       error => {

        console.log('There was an error: ', error);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service needs to use @Injectable() decorator for the class.

e.g.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) //if you want to provide it in a certain module scope. Remove the `providedIn`
export class DocumentTreeService {...
```

If that doesn't fix it on it's own. The following is another way to inject services that have dependencies.

```
let documentTreeService: DocumentTreeService;
beforeEach(async () => {
    for any function name that you need to exist on the spy objects
    const dataSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GlobalDataService', ['funcName']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      //... removed for brevity
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, ...],
      providers: [
           DocumentTreeService,
      { provide: GlobalDataService, useValue: dataSpy }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
   //To access the service from your tests
      documentTreeService = TestBed.inject(DocumentTreeService);
  });
```

Comment: Shouldn't `HttpTestingModule` be somehow provided instead?

Comment: Also I'm getting ` Cannot find name 'documentTreeService'. Did you mean 'DocumentTreeService'?`

Comment: I also removed GlobalDataService from the providers array

Comment: Is this the correct imports array?: `imports: [ TreeviewModule.forRoot(), ReactiveFormsModule, MatProgressBarModule,
         BrowserModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, HttpClientTestingModule, MatDialogModule, MatInputModule
         /* MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule */ ],`

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. Replace MasterService with your DocumentTreeService. I've edited my answer. Yes you can provide http testing module in your imports which *should* work as well.

Comment: ` Cannot find name 'documentTreeService'. Did you mean 'DocumentTreeService'?` For this error what line is it happening on? Make sure you have included the declaration at the top of the code block in my answer which declares it for use in your tests.

Comment: the error happens on this line: `documentTreeService = TestBed.inject(DocumentTreeService);` I also sent in the code as it looks now in my IDE in the question above

Comment: Yes so you need to add the following line outside your beforeEach but inside your test suite at a scope that all your tests can see. (This is usually just above your beforeEach() function like you can see in my answer). `let documentTreeService: DocumentTreeService;`

Comment: My bad, I actually forgot to copy-paste that part. But now I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Comment: Great! That sounds like we have fixed your original issue as your tests are now running. I think you can confirm this by removing your `expect(component).toBeTruthy();` test as that will be testing something subscribing in your component. It might be a different question to solve this issue. Although put your component code so we can see. However, I think your service import and bounty question are solved.

Comment: I updated the question. I hoped for that fixing this error would make the test run and the component would be truthy (a.k.a. initialised) properly, that's why I formulated the bounty description that way. Reducing my amount of tests to 0 doesn't really solve my problem though...

Comment: Removing the line is just a debugging step. Thanks for adding your component code. It appears that the error you posted above is now due to the get method not existing on your service. Since you're importing the `HttpClientTestingModule` you can remove the spy that we made (both of these do the same thing and I think the spy is overriding the module) `{ provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpSpy }` I've updated my answer to show this

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! I will award you the bounty in 3 days.

Answer (score 3):

Your `DocumentTreeService` is using `HttpClient` and `GlobalDataService` and you're not providing them in the `TestBed` module. I would mock the `DocumentTreeService` and not provide the actual service when testing the component.

```
describe('DocumentTreeviewComponent', () => {
  let component: DocumentTreeviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DocumentTreeviewComponent>;
  let mockDocumentTreeService = jasmine.createSpyObj('documentTreeService', ['getDocItems']); // add this line, also look into how to mock external dependencies such as a service  
// !! Remove the <DocumentTreeService> on the above line !!

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DocumentTreeviewComponent ],
      imports: [ TreeviewModule.forRoot(), ReactiveFormsModule, MatProgressBarModule,
         BrowserModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, /* MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule */ ],
      providers: [{ provide: DocumentTreeService, useValue: mockDocumentTreeService }] // modify this line to provide a mock
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DocumentTreeviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mockDocumentTreeService.getDocItems().and.returnValue([]); // we have mocked getDocItems to return an empty array. You can return anything you want for that function.
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please give an example by editing your code?

Comment: I have added `getDocItems` and mocked what it should return.

Comment: `Property 'and' does not exist on type 'TreeviewItem[]'.` :/

Comment: Try removing the `<DocumentTreeService>`. I have made an update.

Comment: Now I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: P.S I'm using the `import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';`

Comment: And are you putting the `HttpClientTestingModule` in the `imports` array of the `TestBed`. I don't see where you are doing `http.get`.

Comment: `http.get` happens in the DocumentTreeview Component ts file...

Comment: Make sure you have `imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]`.

Comment: I do have that imported

Comment: I am not sure then :/

Comment: I setup a bounty as motivation

Comment: Try having it the way I have it as and remove the line `mockDocumentTreeService.getDocItems().and.returnValue([]);`.

Comment: That didn't help :/

Comment: AFAIK an error like `Can't resolve all parameters` doesnt mean you're not providing them but rather Angular compiler can't recognize types of constructor parameters, meaning it requires `@Injectable` or `@Inject` decorators

Comment: Then maybe James is right. It needs the `@Injectable` decorator and it needs to be mocked this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing a unit test, you only want to test the component and not any of its dependencies. Optimally, you can Mock all other components declared, as well as all providers.

A good library for this is [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks). Then, instead of being forced to check your service along with your component, you can just mock it.

```
providers: [ DocumentTreeService ]
```

can then be changed to

```
providers: [ {
    provide: DocumentTreeService ,
    useValue: MockService(DocumentTreeService)
}]
```

That way you can separate the external service from your component's unit test